# How to make Qweb Report Accessible to Public User?

Tags: reactjs, odoo, odoo-14, odoo-15, odoo-16

I am Trying to access Report URL http://192.168.0.158:8020/report/pdf/account.report_invoice/20
But it is asking me to login. I want my report to be accessible to an user outside of odoo. How can i achieve this?

Comment: I don't have a good answer but a hint: try to find out how Odoo is doing that in the sales portal. There is a portal view for quotations with a print button in it.

Answer (score 0):

To give the public user access, you also need to make all the corresponding records (models) used by the report accessible. (Not a good idea for invoice reports).

For a custom report, you can use a controller and set the authentication to public (`auth="public"`), render the report in sudo mode and make a response